# Javascript Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm hoping you can assist with this weird issue.  I have the code below, when I open it as a web-page, just a straight .html, it works fine.  No problems.  When I imbed it onto a SharaPoint page I get two errors:

1. 'Timeline' is undefined
2. Unable to get value of the property 'layout': object is null or undefined.  This is happening for the tl.layout(); function way down at the bottom.

I've added in two comments to show where the errors are being tagged in the debugger.  I'm completely stumped as the code works fine on its own, and I'm not sure how its 'losing' its definitions?

```
    <class="javascript" style="border: 1px solid #b4d0dc; background-color: #ecf8ff;">
<html>  
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
     Timeline_ajax_url="/sites/abc/Shared%20Documents/timeline_front/timeline_ajax/simile-ajax-api.js";
     Timeline_urlPrefix='sites/abc/Shared%20Documents/timeline_front/timeline_js/';
     Timeline_parameters='bundle=true'        
    </script>
    <script>
    </script>   
<script src="/sites/abc/Shared%20Documents/timeline_front/timeline_js/timeline-api.js"type="text/javascript">
    </script>   

<script type="text/javascript">

var tl;
var eventSource = new Timeline.DefaultEventSource();  //ERROR IS HAPPENING HERE.  

function openXMLfile(url)
{        
    if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
        {                
        xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                try {                        
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
                        } catch (e) {
                        alert("Permission UniversalBrowserRead denied.");
                        }
                xmlDoc.async=false;
                xmlDoc.load(url);
                return(xmlDoc);
        }        
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async="false";
                xmlDoc.load(url);
                return(xmlDoc); 
        }
        else
        {
                alert('Your browser cannot handle this script');
                return;
        }        
}

function takeEventOut(url)
{        
    var rows;
        xmlDoc = openXMLfile(url);

        if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
        {
            try {
                        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
                        } catch (e) {
                        alert("Permission UniversalBrowserRead denied.");
                        }      
            var rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row");
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
                rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
        }
        else
        {       
            alert('Your browser cannot handle this script');
                return;
        }

        for (j=0;j<rows.length;j++)
        {
            // taking the event info from the xml
                var rawDateEvent = rows.item(j).getAttribute('ows_StartDate');
                var rawEndEvent = rows.item(j).getAttribute('ows_EndDate');
                var eventTitle = rows.item(j).getAttribute('ows_LinkTitle');
                var status = rows.item(j).getAttribute('ows_Activity');
                var priority = rows.item(j).getAttribute('ows_Activity');
                var EventIDTag = rows.item(j).getAttribute('ows_ID');
                var iconImage;
                iconImage = "/sites/abc/Shared%20Documents/Timeline/timeline_js/images/dark-red-circle.png";

        var dateArray = rawDateEvent.split("#");
                var dateEvent = dateArray[1];
        dateArray = rawEndEvent.split("#");
                var endEvent = dateArray[1];

        //var dateEvent = "Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600";
        //var endEvent = "Thu Feb 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600";

        var eventDays = rows.item(j).getAttribute('ows_IsLong');
        dateArray = eventDays.split("#");
        var IsMultiCheck = dateArray[1];

            // chossing color for the event
                var color;
                color = "blue";
        if(IsMultiCheck=="true"){
            var evt = new Timeline.DefaultEventSource.Event({
                'start': new Date(dateEvent),
                'isDuration': IsMultiCheck,
                'description': eventTitle + "",
                'title': eventTitle + "",
            'icon': iconImage
                    });
        evt._title = eventTitle;
        evt._instant = true;
        evt._text = eventTitle + "";
        evt._link = "/abc/Lists/Operations/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + EventIDTag;
        } else {
            var evt = new Timeline.DefaultEventSource.Event({
                'start': new Date(dateEvent),
                        'end': new Date(endEvent),
                'isDuration': IsMultiCheck,
                'title': eventTitle + "",
            'description': eventTitle + ""
                });
        evt._title = eventTitle;
        evt._instant = false;
        evt._text = eventTitle + "";
        evt._link = "/abc/Lists/Operations/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + EventIDTag;
        }

        //PrintObject is for debugging               
        //printObject(evt);

        // adding it to the source
                eventSource.add(evt);
        }
}

function printObject(o) {
  var out = '';
  for (var p in o) {
    out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
  }
  alert(out);
}


function onLoad()
{

    takeEventOut("/sites/abc/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={GUID}    
&View={GUID}&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=");          //create the timeline
    var bandInfos = [
        Timeline.createBandInfo({
                trackGap:       0.2,
                width:          "70%",
        date:           "8 Aug 2014",
                intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.DAY,
                intervalPixels: 50,
        timeZone:       -6,
                eventSource:    eventSource,
        layout:         'original'  // original, overview, detailed
                }),
    Timeline.createBandInfo({
                trackHeight:    0.5,
                trackGap:       0.2,
                width:          "30%",
        timeZone:       -6,
                date:       "8 Aug 2014",
                intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.MONTH,
                intervalPixels: 150,
                eventSource:    eventSource,
        layout:         'overview'  // original, overview, detailed
                })
        ];          
    bandInfos[1].syncWith = 0;
        bandInfos[1].highlight = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < bandInfos.length; i++) {
                bandInfos[i].decorators = [
                    new Timeline.SpanHighlightDecorator({
                        startDate:  "Sun Jun 22 2014 12:30:00 GMT-0600",
                        endDate:    "Fri Aug 15 2014 13:00:00 GMT-0600",
                        color:      "#FFC080",
                        opacity:    50,
                        startLabel: "Block Begins",
                        endLabel:   "Block Ends",
                       // theme:      theme,
                       cssClass: 't-highlight1'
                    })
                ];
            }

        tl = Timeline.create(document.getElementById("my-timeline"), bandInfos);
}

var resizeTimerID = null;
function onResize() {
        if (resizeTimerID == null) {
        resizeTimerID = window.setTimeout(function() {
            resizeTimerID = null;
            tl.layout();  //SECOND ERROR IS HERE
        }, 500);
    }
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();" onresize="onResize();">
     <div id="my-timeline" style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid #aaa"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like `timeline-api.js` isn't loading properly. Check the Network tab in the console.

Comment: Is the path to your 'timeline-api.js' file the same on both Sharepoint and your local environment

Comment: @ Barmar, what exactly should I be looking for in the network tab?  All the URL GET's are coming back as result 304.  Its weird, if I go to the document library and just browse to the page by clicking on it, works fine.  For some reason it hates being imbedded on a SharePoint page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be down to the line

```
<script src="/sites/abc/Shared%20Documents/timeline_front/timeline_js/timeline-api.js"type="text/javascript">
     </script>
```

Check the script source and that it is pointing to the right file. SharePoint might be looking for the file in a different place than IE

The second error results from the first error, as it cannot do anything to an undefined object. The object Timeline is undefined most probably because the script src is wrong

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I used the network tab of the IE debugger and all the file get's came back as good.  Weirder now is I don't even seem to get the undefined error, the functions don't even seem to be running.

Comment: Okay, well it seems after hitting the F5 a bit, its back to the same error.  Is there a way to force timeline-api.js to load before anything else?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Would probably need some googling.